# Где сказуемое?

Tags: сказуемые, грамотная-речь

Грамотны ли такие выражения, как, например: *"Видеть - это когда ты смотришь"*. Я имею в виду конструкции *"это когда"*.  
Пока писал вопрос, вспомнил, что моя школьная учительница авторитетно заявляла о том, что такие конструкции неграмотны, так как нет сказуемого. Так ли это?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

На форуме очень часто задают вопросы, касающиеся структуры предложения. Я объясню свое видение ситуации, нисколько не претендуя на полное освещение проблемы. Хочется, чтобы филологи, которые не так давно закончили обучение, или преподаватели вузов дополнили меня или исправили. Потому что я закончила филологический факультет университета почти 30 лет назад,  25 лет работаю в школе, т.е. дело имею не с научной грамматикой, а со школьной.

Почему многие предложения так трудно разобрать по членам?
1. Традиционный синтаксис русского языка развивался как синтаксис правильной, книжной речи. *Известный русский психолог и лингвист Н. И. Жинкин однажды заметил: “Как это ни парадоксально, я думаю, что лингвисты долгое время изучали человека молчащего”. И был совершенно прав. Долгое время считалось, что говорят так же или примерно так же, как и пишут. Только в 60-е гг. нашего столетия, когда появилась возможность фиксировать разговорную речь с помощью магнитофонов и эта речь попала в полном объеме в поле зрения лингвистов, выяснилось, что для лингвистического осмысления разговорной речи существующие кодификации не вполне пригодны.* (Из учебника по культуре речи, я согласна полностью).А в последние два десятилетия особенностью официальной, книжной речи  (журналы. газеты,  телевидении и радио) является хлынувший поток разговорной, неофициальной речи. Это касается не только синтаксиса. но и грамматики. Мы уже так наслушались этой смеси, что стали привыкать. И вот пытаемся разобрать предложение разговорного стиля по канонам формального (традиционного, структурного) синтаксиса. А он основан на анализе других предложений.

Художественная речь - она особенная, у нее свои задачи и свои законы. Поэтому не буду трогать Пришвина. Но представим себе, что это ответ на вопрос:"Что такое осень?" Возможный ответ, правильно построенный (я не о содержании): "Осень - это время, когда падают листья" Структура ясна? Сложноподчиненное предложение, первая основа  - *Осень* - подлежащее, *время*- сказуемое, вторая - *падают листья*. И почему ставится тире, тоже понятно. И про то, что *когда* - средство связи в СПП.  В разговорной речи происходит трансформация:  осень -это когда...  Видеть - это когда... Потому что сразу не могут подобрать нужное слово, устная речь быстрая, вот и появляется это универсальное *это когда*. Вместо"счастье - это любовь" - "Счастье это когда любят". Я не хочу сказать, что так нельзя говорить. Говорить можно. А письменная речь подчиняется другим законам. Именно потому так трудно излагать свои мысли на бумаге. 
Итак, я вижу причину возникающих трудностей в том, что мы предложения разговорной речи пытаемся анализировать средствами формального синтаксиса, основанного на анализе правильных предложений. 
(То ли анекдот. то ли байка. Мальчик показывает на волчьи ягоды и спрашивает:"Эти эти ягоды можно есть?" -  "Есть - можно. только отравишься". )

Предложение из вопроса - явно разговорного характера. В ситуации общения оно понятно. На письме выглядит странно.

1. Я помню, что, кроме формального синтаксиса , есть еще семантический, логический, коммуникативный, какой-то еще и еще. Так вот членение предложения  в этих синтаксических теориях не совпадает. Например, в предложении "Мне холодно" с точки зрения традиционной подлежащего нет (формально: подлежащее имеет форму им.п.), с точки зрения не помню какого синтаксиса логическое подлежащее "мне" (Ведь предмет речи - я?). А мы при анализе предложения смешиваем эти подходы. Вот и получается у нас, что сказуемое выражено предложением. С точки зрения традиционного синтаксиса - полная ерунда! С точки зрения другой теории (коммуникативного, наверное, синтаксиса?) - почему нет. По смыслу -то так и получается. 
   Я привыкла к синтаксису традиционному, формальному, именно он представлен в школьном курсе. Поэтому если я вижу несколько предикативных частей и между ними союз *когда*, я знаю, что это сложноподчиненное предложение, а никак не простое.

Comment: @Ларf, очень интересно читать. Особенно про лингвистов и человека  молчащего (homo elinguem?)  
Но не слишком ли всё это тяжелая артиллерия для нашего вопроса? Я сейчас не буду про формальный синтаксис (я академиев не кончал, в силу своей серости, немного не так всю ситуацию вижу), но вот по сути...  
Возьмем, чтобы не заморачиваться с "видеть" и "смотреть", всё-таки самую известную школьную фразу "Счастье - это когда тебя понимают".
Я как рассуждаю. Отталкиваясь, к примеру, от "Счатье - это любовь" меняем "любовь" на все, что заблагорассудится, не трогая грамматики. 
Дальше, думаю, понятно.

Comment: Нет, понятно не очень. Вы имеете в виду, что все, что заменяет сказуемое "любовь" - это тоже сказуемое? Помнится, есть такое выражение "группа сказуемого". Или это здесь не к месту?

Comment: Ну да, опуская промежуточные рассуждения, полягаю, что грамматика у этих фраз должна быть одинакова. "Группа сказуемого", если не ошибаюсь, это терминологический прием, чтобы не оговаривать каждый раз возможность распространённости этого сказуемого. Если так, то это здесь не существенно.  
Просто надо сравнить грамматику и синтаксис двух фраз - и либо признать их эквивалентность (тогда ничего не отанется как признать, что "предложение" действительно может стать сказуемым), либо четко обозначить, в чем принципиальная разница в структуре. Но я её, разницу, тут не вижу.

Comment: Добавил мысли по этому поводу в свой ответ.

Comment: >Почему многие предложения так трудно разобрать по членам?

Я не вижу тут проблемы.
Потому, что грамматика объектива, а любое её описание - субъективно. Грубо говоря то, что мы называем грамматикой еть лишь её модель. И как вяская модель весьма ограничена.

Answer (score 2):

Предложения могут иметь неполную структуру. В частности, сказуемое может быть опущено в том случае, если основной смысл предложения заключен во второстепенных членах предложения.

В качестве примера в голову сразу приходит известная цитата из Шопенгауэра:

*"Первая и по сути единственная предпосылка хорошего стиля - это когда человеку есть что сказать."*

**Дополнение:**

Воспользуюсь предложением [[@Ларf](/users/498/%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%80f)](/users/498/%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%80f) дополнить освещение проблемы и дам свой ответ на вопрос о том, почему всё так сложно. Как справедливо замечено, корень проблемы действительно кроется в том, что литературный язык и разговорная речь существенно отличаются друг от друга. Но структурное различие существует не между письменной и устной формой.

Форма выражения не очень сильно влияет на структуру. Гораздо сильнее она влияет на семантику. Мой любимый пример на эту тему: "американцы слишком много жрут". Эта фраза может иметь один из двух совершенно различных смыслов: "жители США употребляют слишком много пищи" или "автомобили американского производства потребляют слишком много топлива". В письменной форме фраза имеет только первый смысл. Второй смысл может появиться только в разговоре. Этот разговор, конечно, может быть записан (напр. в виде сообщения на форуме [avto.ru](http://avto.ru)), но это не то же самое, что настоящая письменная форма выражения. Синтаксическая структура при этом остаётся неизменной. Хотя это совершенно другое высказывание.

На структуру же существенным образом влияет различие между языком и речью. Грубо говоря, структурная пропасть между литературным языком и разговорной речью обусловлена не разницей между письменным и устным. Она обусловлена тем, что литературный язык - это язык, а разговорная речь - это речь. Т.е. проблема не с формой, а с содержанием. Понятия "язык" и "речь" взаимосвязаны отнюдь не так тесно, как принято считать. Фактически, мы имеем дело с двумя принципиально разными вещами. Это различие было выявлено ещё Де Соссюром. Полагаю, именно за это его и считают отцом-основателем лингвистики. Если попытаться выразить его идеи в двух словах, то их суть в том, что язык - это коллективная вещь, а речь - в существенной степени индивидуальная. У них просто не может быть единой структуры. Уже хотя бы потому, что отдельные люди, когда общаются друг с другом, не заморачиваются по поводу какой-то там структуры, и их речь вообще слабо структурирована. Другое дело - писатели и журналисты. Они адресуют свои тексты миллионам разных людей, и поэтому вынуждены придерживаться какой-то общей для всех структуры. Т.е. в их случае коммуникация происходит не столько речевым образом, сколько на языке. Хотя, конечно, у каждого автора есть свои индивидуальные особенности, которые проявляются и в письменной речи.

В русской же речи всё ещё хуже. Это связано с особенностями, которые привнесены в нашу культуру Римским правом. На первый взгляд, юридическая правовая система не имеет никакого отношения к языку. Но это не так. В обоих случаях речь идёт о нормативных правилах (юридические нормы и языковые нормы). У Римского права есть одна особенность. В нём не принято формулировать и закреплять в виде правил вещи, которые всем очевидны, и поэтому выполняются естественным образом. Везде, где это возможно, активно применяется принцип "исключение подтверждает правило". Т.е. само правило не формулируется вообще (за ненадобностью), а фиксируются лишь некоторые исключения из него. Само правило как бы подразумевается и действует во всех неисключительных случаях. В языке это проявляется через такие вещи, как надпись на двери "посторонним вход воспрещён". В других культурах пишут "служебный вход" или "только для персонала". Или другой пример, подсмотренный мной в жизни, - листочек на офисной микроволновке с надписью "рыбу и морепродукты не разогревать". В нём нет ни слова о том, что можно разогревать. Просто зафиксированы исключения. И я подозреваю, что таких примеров в речевой практике можно найти множество. И к своему языку русские люди относятся примерно так же. Не воспринимают языковые правила, как нечто естественно необходимое. В лучшем случае признают исключения. А в общем случае говорят так, чтобы было понятно.

Короче говоря, различие между языком и речью уже само по себе проблематизирует единство синтаксической структуры. Разговорная речь перенимает из общего коллективного языка лишь часть его структуры, одновременно дополняя её индивидуальными элементами. Но это у всех так. У русских же ещё есть своя специфика, которая состоит в том, что они вообще не любят сформулированные правила. Из-за этого структура их речи имеет ещё меньше общего со структорой литературного языка. Спасает то, что в художественных произведениях очень много диалогов. Благодаря этому, литературный язык очень активно заимствует из речевой практики, а значит речевые обороты тем или иным образом встраиваются в структуру языка.

Comment: Какое всё это имеет отношение к вопросу?
И вообще вы бы хоть обозначили "проблему", о которой так много говорите.


ЗЫ "Многабукафф. Ниасилел."

Comment: Правильно писать "многабукаф" и "ниасилил". В языке подонков тоже есть правила.

Comment: Может, и не имеет отношения к вопросу. Но интересно. Спасибо.

Comment: @Ларf Вы какой вопрос имеете в виду? Исходный? Или вопрос о том, почему так сложно разбирать предложение по членам? Просто ко второму вопросу это всё имеет самое прямое отношение.

Comment: Исходный, конечно. Как ответ на первую реплику.

Comment: Возможно, имеет смысл создать отдельную тему и перенести второй вопрос туда.

Comment: Задать могу. Но ответы наши останутся здесь?

Comment: Нужно будет их самим вручную перенести. Но вопрос лучше пусть задаст кто-нибудь другой, чтобы не получилось самоответа.

Comment: Вас так забавляет возможность самоответа?
Они здесь не запрещены.
Другое дело, что сам вопрос ни о чем. Стуктуризация пустутоты.
ЗЫ А языка падонкафф вы не знаете. Как и всего того, о чем беретесь писать. Правила там есть, только не те, что вы думаете. Как-нибудь я вам расскажу, когда хорошо себе вести начнёте.

Answer (score 2):

Нашла такую информацию:
 Тире ставится перед словами это, это есть, вот, значит, это значит, присоединяющими сказуемое к подлежащему. Например: Кремль – это сокровищница русского зодчества, творение великих мастеров, живая летопись многовековой истории (Из газет). Все прошедшее, настоящее и будущее – это мы, а не слепая сила стихий (Горький).
Ср.: ***Самая поздняя осень – это когда от морозов рябина сморщится и станет, как говорят, «сладкой» (Пришвин) (в роли сказуемого выступает целое предложение).***(http://www.classes.ru/grammar/127.Rosental-pravopisanie/42.htm)

Ваше предложение по строению такое же, как последний пример в приведённой цитате из Розенталя. Выражение ***"это когда ты смотришь"*** является ***сказуемым*** при подлежащем "видеть". Так что такие конструкции в русском языке существуют на вполне законных основаниях.

Comment: Логика Розенталя понятна. Но Розенталь не грамматист. Где Вы еще встречали упоминание о том, что сказуемое может быть выражено предложением? И какую характеристику тогда мы должны дать этому предложению? Простое? Сложное?

Comment: В том-то и дело, что не встречала нигде! Для меня это открытие. Буду думать и искать. Где-то же это должно оговариваться. Насчёт характеристики: может, предложение становится осложнённым простым?

Comment: Я думаю, в формальном (структурном, традиционном) синтаксисе и не встретите.

Comment: Ларf, систем формальных нграмматик столько, что можно встретить всё, что угодно. Я, прада, уже лет двадцать пять, как этим не занимаюсь, но помнится, с появлением компьюторов пошла просто какая-то эпидемия по написанию формализованных грамматик. Для целей машинного (как тогда говорили, т.е. комрьютерного) перевода.

Answer (score 0):

Я считаю, что такие предложения неграмотны и моя учительница была права.

Comment: Предложения такого типа не то что неграмотны, они несколько разговорного характера. А традиционная классификация членов предложения, как, впрочем, и весь структурный синтаксис, основана на примерах книжных стилей.

Answer (score 0):

Полагаю, в лучшем случае вы недопоняли учительницу. Ну не может она не знать о существовании предложений, где нет сказуемого.

Дальнейшие комментрарии пока приостанавливаю, ибо непонятно, в каком предложении учительница не углядела сказуемого - и как она вообще делает тут грамматический разбор. 
Либо это два предложения "Видеть это [есть]" и "когда ты смотришь" (здесь сказуемое найдет даже первоклассник) , либо, по мнению учительницы, это единое предложение.

Качательно смысловой нагрузки - согласен, фраза крайне неудачная. Видеть - это когда ты смотришь и воспринимаешь. А не просто "смотришь", ничего не видя.

"Счастье - это когда тебя понимают." Как раз про учительницу. И без никаких шопенгауэров.

Comment: Спасибо за ваше мнение. Всегда приятно получить разъяснение по грамматическому вопросу от человека, который использует обороты вроде "без никаких шопенгауэров".

Comment: Согласен, меня не и нтересует мнение человека, который читая Шопенгаэра не в состоянии понять элементарную иронию.
А спасиба мне вашего не надо. В данном случае моё мнение вас не касается.

Comment: Жаль, что мне не удалось осчастливить вас своим пониманием вашей тонкой иронии. Ведь "счастье - это когда тебя понимают".

Comment: Мне тоже жаль. Наверное, Шопенгаура перечитали.

Comment: Уверен, вы правы. Во всём виноват именно Шопенгауэр.

Comment: Вот и не читайте его на ночь.

Comment: Может не знать. Учительницы тоже разные бывают. Например, наша преподавательница русского языка и литературы говорила "ездеют"))))

Comment: Если подлежащее "когда ты смотришь", то с какой стати ставиться тире?