# Двоеточие или тире между подлежащим и сказуемым в форме предложения

Tags: синтаксис, сказуемые, тире, подлежащее, двоеточие

**Первое важное правило, которое нужно запомнить (двоеточие / запятая + тире) почти в любой компании карьерный рост нужен только работнику.**

С одной стороны, по смыслу тут просматривается подлежащее "первое важное правило" и сказуемое — само содержание правила; однако сказуемое не может быть выражено целой клаузой.

Очень хочется поставить двоеточие, однако двоеточие ставится в бессоюзных предложениях, где есть две грамматические основы, а также при пояснении первой части предложения, в котором есть своя грамматическая основа, как в примерах:

**Все они [письма] о главном: перестройке в нашей жизни.**

**Настроение одно: скорее добраться до дома.**

Ни разу не видел примеров пунктуации, чтобы ставилось двоеточие, а первая часть предложения была незаконченной: имелось только подлежащее и при этом односоставной эту часть предложения никак не назовёшь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Думаю, тут два подхода возможны.

1. **Первое важное правило, которое нужно запомнить, — почти в любой компании карьерный рост нужен только работнику.**

Считаем, что предложение "почти в любой компании карьерный рост нужен только работнику" является сказуемым. Тире ставится между подлежащим и сказуемым. Идея спорная, но у Розенталь можно найти похожий пример (в роли сказуемого выступает целое предложение):

> 3.Тире ставится перед словами это, это есть, вот, значит, это значит, присоединяющими сказуемое к подлежащему. Например: Кремль – это сокровищница русского зодчества, творение великих мастеров, живая летопись многовековой истории (Из газет). Все прошедшее, настоящее и будущее – это мы, а не слепая сила стихий (Горький).
>   Ср.: Самая поздняя осень – это когда от морозов рябина сморщится и станет, как говорят, «сладкой» (Пришвин) (**в роли сказуемого выступает целое предложение**).

http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/42.htm

[Здесь](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/8955/%D0%93%D0%B4%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%83%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B5) этот вопрос обсуждался весьма подробно.

2. **Первое важное правило, которое нужно запомнить: почти в любой компании карьерный рост нужен только работнику.**

Считаем, что у нас БСП. Первое предложение либо назывное, либо сказуемое ("гласит") опущено. Вторая часть раскрывает содержание первой. Ставится двоеточие.